# gdb watchpoint not activated

Tags: c, gdb, watchpoint

Consider the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int update (int *arr, int size);

#define SIZE 10

int main() { // <---------------------- Breakpoint 1
  int x[SIZE];

  // Initialize array
  for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
    x[c] = c * 2;
  }

  // Do some random updates to an array
  update((int*) &x, SIZE);

  // Print the elements
  for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
    printf("%d\n", x[c]);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} //            <----------------------Breakpoint 2

int update (int *arr, int size) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    arr[i] += i;
    update(arr+i, size-1);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Result of running `info frame` at breakpoint 1:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7ffc176b2610:
 rip = 0x56434b0d76b8 in main (array.c:12); saved rip = 0x7f8190fb92b1
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7ffc176b2600, args:
 Locals at 0x7ffc176b2600, Previous frame's sp is 0x7ffc176b2610
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7ffc176b2600, rip at 0x7ffc176b2608
```

Result of running `info frame` at breakpoint 2:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7ffc176b2610:
 rip = 0x56434b0d771a in main (array.c:24); saved rip = 0x2d28490fd6501
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7ffc176b2600, args:
 Locals at 0x7ffc176b2600, Previous frame's sp is 0x7ffc176b2610
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7ffc176b2600, rip at 0x7ffc176b2608
```

We see that `main()`'s saved return address `rip at 0x7ffc176b2608` is mutated from `0x7f8190fb92b1` to `0x2d28490fd6501` between the two breakpoints.

However, setting a watchpoint on the address of `rip` with `watch * 0x7ffc176b2608` and running the executable anew does not pause execution between the breakpoints as expected.

How can this be?

**-----------EDIT-----------**

Output of `disassemble /s main`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
array.c:
8   int main() {
   0x000056434b0d76b0 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000056434b0d76b1 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000056434b0d76b4 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x30

9     int x[SIZE];
10  
11    // Initialize array
12    for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
   0x000056434b0d76b8 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000056434b0d76bf <+15>:    jmp    0x56434b0d76d4 <main+36>

13      x[c] = c * 2;
   0x000056434b0d76c1 <+17>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d76c4 <+20>:    lea    edx,[rax+rax*1]
   0x000056434b0d76c7 <+23>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d76ca <+26>:    cdqe   
   0x000056434b0d76cc <+28>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*4-0x30],edx

12    for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
   0x000056434b0d76d0 <+32>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x000056434b0d76d4 <+36>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x000056434b0d76d8 <+40>:    jle    0x56434b0d76c1 <main+17>

14    }
15  
16    // Do some random updates to an array
17    update((int*) &x, SIZE);
   0x000056434b0d76da <+42>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x30]
   0x000056434b0d76de <+46>:    mov    esi,0xa
   0x000056434b0d76e3 <+51>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x000056434b0d76e6 <+54>:    call   0x56434b0d7721 <update>

18  
19    // Print the elements
20    for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
   0x000056434b0d76eb <+59>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
   0x000056434b0d76f2 <+66>:    jmp    0x56434b0d7714 <main+100>

21      printf("%d\n", x[c]);
   0x000056434b0d76f4 <+68>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x000056434b0d76f7 <+71>:    cdqe   
   0x000056434b0d76f9 <+73>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*4-0x30]
   0x000056434b0d76fd <+77>:    mov    esi,eax
   0x000056434b0d76ff <+79>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0x12e]        # 0x56434b0d7834
   0x000056434b0d7706 <+86>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000056434b0d770b <+91>:    call   0x56434b0d7560 <printf@plt>

20    for (int c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++) {
   0x000056434b0d7710 <+96>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1
   0x000056434b0d7714 <+100>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x9
   0x000056434b0d7718 <+104>:   jle    0x56434b0d76f4 <main+68>

22    }
23  
24    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
=> 0x000056434b0d771a <+106>:   mov    eax,0x0

25  }
   0x000056434b0d771f <+111>:   leave  
   0x000056434b0d7720 <+112>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Output of `disassemble /s update`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function update:
array.c:
27  int update (int *arr, int size) {
   0x000056434b0d7721 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000056434b0d7722 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000056434b0d7725 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x20
   0x000056434b0d7729 <+8>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
   0x000056434b0d772d <+12>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],esi

28    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
   0x000056434b0d7730 <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000056434b0d7737 <+22>:    jmp    0x56434b0d7793 <update+114>

29      arr[i] += i;
   0x000056434b0d7739 <+24>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d773c <+27>:    cdqe   
   0x000056434b0d773e <+29>:    lea    rdx,[rax*4+0x0]
   0x000056434b0d7746 <+37>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x000056434b0d774a <+41>:    add    rax,rdx
   0x000056434b0d774d <+44>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d7750 <+47>:    movsxd rdx,edx
   0x000056434b0d7753 <+50>:    lea    rcx,[rdx*4+0x0]
   0x000056434b0d775b <+58>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x000056434b0d775f <+62>:    add    rdx,rcx
   0x000056434b0d7762 <+65>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rdx]
   0x000056434b0d7764 <+67>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d7767 <+70>:    add    edx,ecx
   0x000056434b0d7769 <+72>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rax],edx

30      update(arr+i, size-1);
   0x000056434b0d776b <+74>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c]
   0x000056434b0d776e <+77>:    lea    edx,[rax-0x1]
   0x000056434b0d7771 <+80>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d7774 <+83>:    cdqe   
   0x000056434b0d7776 <+85>:    lea    rcx,[rax*4+0x0]
   0x000056434b0d777e <+93>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x000056434b0d7782 <+97>:    add    rax,rcx
   0x000056434b0d7785 <+100>:   mov    esi,edx
   0x000056434b0d7787 <+102>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x000056434b0d778a <+105>:   call   0x56434b0d7721 <update>

28    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
   0x000056434b0d778f <+110>:   add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x000056434b0d7793 <+114>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000056434b0d7796 <+117>:   cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c]
   0x000056434b0d7799 <+120>:   jl     0x56434b0d7739 <update+24>

31    }
32    return 1;
   0x000056434b0d779b <+122>:   mov    eax,0x1

33  }
   0x000056434b0d77a0 <+127>:   leave  
   0x000056434b0d77a1 <+128>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Contents of `~/.gdbinit`

```
# Security
set auto-load safe-path /

# Misc
set disassembly-flavor intel
set disable-randomization off
set pagination off
set follow-fork-mode child

# History
set history filename ~/.gdbhistory
set history save
set history expansion

disp/10i $pc

handle SIGXCPU SIG33 SIG35 SIGPWR nostop noprint

set tui enable
```

Comment: how was the code compiled? how was the code linked? did you use the `gcc` compiler? did you use the `-g` (or better `-ggdb`) option?  What were the commands given to `gdb`?

Comment: @user3629249 with `gcc-6 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -g array.c`. Commands given are described in the text (`b main`, `b 25` for breakpoints).

Comment: Can you show the disassembly (`disas /s` in gdb)? gcc tends to be configured with different default options on each platform, which can affect code generation and data layout. When I run your program, I get oodles of hits on the watchpoint, because the calls to `update(arr+i, size-1);` ultimately clobbers part of the stack. (Should it be `update(arr+i, size-i);`?)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have added disassemblies for `main()` and `update()`.

Comment: @Einar Do you have anything in your `~/.gdbinit`? Can you show your *entire* GDB session, including version banner? (I can't reproduce the lack of watchpoint firing either.)

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have added my `.gdbinit`. I am not sure how to save my entire GDB session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that this line in your `.gdbinit` is the source of your troubles:

```
set disable-randomization off
```

By default, GDB disables address space layout randomization ([ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). That means that the binary under GDB starts at exactly the same address, with exactly the same stack pointer every time it runs. This is on by default *precisely* so you can set a watchpoints and breakpoints on a given address, and have it fire on each run.

By setting `disable-randomization` off, you are asking GDB to run your binary the same way it would run outside of GDB, i.e. with ASLR enabled. Now the location of stack variables (and globals for a [PIE binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) that you have) will change from run to run, and setting a watchpoint on a given stack address will only work randomly and rarely.

You can confirm that that is the cause by issuing `info frame` and `run` several times. You'll observe that the location where registers are saved changes between runs.

TL;DR: Don't put settings you don't completely understand into your `.gdbinit`.

Comment: The OP ask about a single run of the code, so this is not the source of the problem.  see the comment by @Mark Plotnick for the actual source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I put `set disable-randomization off` there with the intend to disable ASLR, but the double negation must have confused me back then.

I still don't understand it fully. Even though the addresses changes between runs, I specifically probe the address of `rip` with `info frame` and put a watchpoint on exactly that address. The content on this address _is_ confirmingly modified, so I still feel it should trigger the watchpoint, regardless of if the address was randomly selected or not.

Comment: Actually it runs exactly as predicted. I must have used `run` instead of continue after setting the watchpoint originally.

Answer (score -1):

the problem with the code is the clobbering of the stack.

The comment by @Mark Plotnick clarifies the problem and includes a suggestion on how to fix it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why watchpoint didn't fire.

Comment: @EmployedRussian,  Actually, the commands to `gdb` are setting break points, not watch points.  And on my computer, it works perfectly.  However, I would suggest setting the break point on the `return` statement rather than the final closing brace '}' because execution has already exited the program at the `return` statement.  (for me, it works because both statements are at the same address.

Comment: Actually, the question is about watchpoints: "However, setting a watchpoint on the address of rip with watch * 0x7ffc176b2608 and running the executable anew does not pause execution between the breakpoints as expected." The breakpoints are secondary to the gist of the question.

Comment: @EmployedRussian,  the OP stated that they used 'b' for the commands.   That sets a breakpoint.  a watchpoint is set with the `watch` or `awatch` or `rwatch` commands

Comment: I am not sure what part of "setting a **watchpoint** ... with `watch * 0x7ffc176b2608`" you didn't understand. In any case, further discussion here is pointless and I'll refrain from it.